# Have I been hacked? Vimeo embedded videos are on my site (apparently?)

Tags: wordpress, vimeo

This is odd...

I have a WordPress site with a Learning Management System. I am getting a ton of emails from people saying why I have embedded their copyright videos on my site?

Is this a spoof - can a hacker someone spoof analytics?

Here's my question though: how can I search for embedded Vimeo Videos on my site? Where could I seek embeds in WordPress?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your URL? Do you not see any videos? You could look to search your DB for a string like 'vimeo'.

Comment: Ok thanks for that tip. What command could I give in SQL to search for that string?

Comment: share your website url we will find out if it has any vimeo videos.

Answer (score 0):

This might a php code injection so you should also try to search for it in your php files as well.

Try downloading the whole theme folder and plugins folder (with all plugins). Then you would need to run search across all those files. Usually malware code is using eval functions so you should search for eval across all those files. Searching one by one would take forever so use grep tool.

For windows I would recommend windows grep http://www.wingrep.com/

For Mac I would recommend visualGrep app which is paid app and costs around 2 bucks but totally worth it.

If you have linux then you would need to find the software yourself or you can run such a search from the command line. (Actually you can use CLI on any system but I just prefer having app with GUI fur such task)

in 99% of cases (from my experience) you will find something like:

```
eval(base64_decode('dsalkndsalndsadkasnldakslasdkn'));
```

That will be the malware code and you should take care of it (remove). If the code is in the plugin, then you should get rid of such a plugin probably.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful. What should I be searching for? I bought visualGrep which is a good app easy to use - and I searched for > eval(base64_decode < but no joy. Are there other search variables I could use? Thanks!

Comment: search for separate words: eval, base64_decode  if nothing found, than probably the malicious code is not even hidden and it is clearly declared. Try to export database and then open the exported .sql file and search in it for "video" or "embed" or "iframe" (in case video tags are saved in the database already). There are many different ways it can be embeded there so you need to keep searching